# Import Excel and Preview it with Datatables PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables, datasource

I'm confusing about how to preview (before users really sure about the data and click save) my excel data in my view. What I've done was importing excel data to the controller, it has already done, but I'm losing my way to reach what I want.
Preview it in my view CodeIgniter.

My Controller:

```
public function import(){
   if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
      $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      include APPPATH.'libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';
      $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
      $worksheet = $object->getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
        $params['highestRow']=$highestRow;
            for($row=4; $row<=$highestRow; $row++){
                $lineno  = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue(); //a
                $account = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue(); //b
                $tambahan= $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue(); //c
            }
   }
   $data[] = array(
           'ACCOUNT'        => $account,
           'LININO'         => $lineno,
           'tambahan'       => $tambahan
         );
   $this->session->set_flashdata('messageupload',$data);
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This is my view `datatable`, and javascript trigger when the `button import was clicked`:

```
var table = $('#tblmemorialdetil').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "400px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         true,
        bInfo        : false,
        lengthChange: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false, targets: 0 },
            { orderable: false, targets: -1 }
        ],
        ordering: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
        
    });



    $('#upload_excel').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
             $.ajax({
                 url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/fin/memorial2/M_index/import',
                 type:"post",
                 data:new FormData(this),
                 processData:false,
                 contentType:false,
                 cache:false,
                    success: function(data){
                        response=JSON.parse(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Pastikan Format Excel yang anda upload sudah merupakan versi terbaru!");
                    }
             });
    });
```

As we can se, I'm just stuck on that point. What I have on my mind was try to entering some aray into session. And what's next? I don't even know how to put all of my array after in view to put in rows and columns.

Is there any ideas to make it better,or atleast much easier to do it. Thanks

Comment: why don't you open a `modal` on `ajax success` and show the `data` in tabular form(like excel) there?

Comment: Or you can first show the data in a `modal` in `excel format` and ask the user to confirm it, then import the data.